# Raspberry Pi B+ direct interface with usb camera

Tags: usb, camera

I would like to know if it is possible to connect usb cameras directly with RPi B+?
While working with RPi Model B, I had to use a powered USB hub to interface with my i-ball camera, but with 4 ports in B+, is it possible to interface the camera directly, without a powered hub? The camera which I'm planning to use needs an input of 5V/1A. The RPi can deliver upto a max of 1.2A for the 4 usb ports.

Also, I am thinking of a project where I would require 2 USB cameras, so is it possible to use 2 usb cameras with the same RPi B+? If I go with the 5V/1A camera, obviously the current rating will go to 2A and the Pi won't be able to deliver it from the usb ports, right?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I have done this myself. Obviously cameras differ, but all I have seen require much less than the 500mA of the USB standard. The camera does NOT `give an output of 5V/1A` it requires a certain current, but it is often difficult to discover the exact value from published specs.

Comment: Hello Ron. Have you ever tested the setup according to your question? I would encourage you to write an answer to present your findings.

Comment: Hi Ghanima, well, one single usb camera did the task which was required for me, so didn't try two cameras at a time. But recently i saw a post that also mentions the usage of 2 such cameras with a single RPi.http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/

Comment: Infact, when I started using RPi Model B, I had to use a USB Hub to work with a single camera and when I switched to Model B+, I could directly connect it to one of the 4 USBs, so I believe its possible, but infact I should have tried it, but due to some constraints, I was not able to.
NB : I haven't tried RPi 2 version. With advancement going on in RPi versions, we can say .. "Why not... , to all the problems that an initial user faced with Model A and Model B."

Answer (score 1):

The [FAQ](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) at raspberrypi.org states a "Maximum total USB peripheral current draw" of 1.2A for the Pi B+. I take it that "maximum total" should be the sum of all downstream ports. In this case it's outside specifications to drive both cameras directly from the Pi's USB ports - if they really draw that much current each.